# How to use orderBy with count method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

Corral model:

```
public function sheeps()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Sheep');
}
```

I want to order by number of sheep in each corral and get corral with fewest sheep number:

```
$corral = Corral::orderBy(..., 'ASC')->first();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of `withCount()` and then order by this element I guess:

```
$corral = Corral
      ::withCount('sheeps')
      ->orderBy('sheeps_count', 'asc')
      ->first();
```

Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) of the documentation.